# Do I have to use <a> tag? Can I not just use .click()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, href

I'm using jQuery and jQuery mobile and I've always leaned towards making clickable events with button/a tags

```
<button id='id'>my button</button>
<a href='#' id='id2'>my anchor</a>
```

I read somewhere that this was previously the recommended standard, but that limit has since been deprecated.

My understanding is the following is not just acceptable, but does not break standards

```
<h1 id="id">abcdef</h1>

<script>
$("#id").click(myFunction);
</script>
```

Am I right? Is it acceptable for me to just apply click events to any tag I want to? (I expect/demand my clients to be less than 3years old)

Comment: Yes you could attach click event to other tags and not just _button/a_ tags...

Comment: That answers that then =) Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can apply click events to any element you want.(If that's what you want to know)

Answer (score 3):

While you can attach a click event handler to most elements, I would advise that you stick to attaching them to an `a`, or a `button`, or any other element which a user *expects* to click, ie. not a `table`, or a `strong`.

This is for two reasons. Firstly, because it's what people expect and having a UI that's as easy for a user to navigate and operate without *thinking* about what they need to do is essential. A user wouldn't think that a large heading is clickable, so it may end up hiding some functionality which they need to use.

Secondly by keeping the events on the standard clickable elements you both keep to accessibility guidelines and can also then provide a graceful redundancy if the JS code fails to work, or is disabled by the client browser.

There are of course exceptions to this, but as a general rule it's one I stick to.

Comment: *"I would advise that you stick to attaching them to a and button elements."* - I disagree, there are quite a few other elements that have good use for the click event.

Comment: Ok, bad wording on my part - I didn't mean that as an exhaustive list. My point is, don't go putting click handlers on things like `p` or `hr` elements. Wrap them in an element which is clickable by default and then deal with the event yourself through JS.

Comment: My H1 tag was just an example - I might well have selected a table, img, span, div or anything else. I knew I *could* but was not sure if I *should avoid* doing it.

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek For example: Images

Comment: I wouldn't have a directly clickable image. I'd wrap it in an `<a>`.

Comment: Why should we put in some extra tags when we can do it directly? Wouldn't it lessen the html?

Comment: It works better for user accessibility as the user can then use the keyboard to navigate to the `a` element containing the `img` (in our example here) and press the return key to fire the click event. If the `img` was not in an `a` it would not be selectable by the keyboard, unless you add a `tabindex` to it, and that's something that's much easier to forget to do. Also I believe in the latter case a screen reader would miss that the `img` would be clickable, but it would recognise a parent `a` around it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it works, I'd say go ahead and do it. Just be consistent.

Generally, I'd say yes, you can apply click events to anything you'd like; keep in mind though this capability varies from browser to browser. I seem to recall having a great deal of trouble trying to get a div to receive a click event at some point in my life.

I'd favor buttons and anchor tags over header tags. Anchor tags can be tabbed over and generally describe a link to something. Header tags are generally more for organizing the content in the page rather than being an interactive element.